# How to get duplicate code of buttons out of Component?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

The following code works fine:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function App() {
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(0); 

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setTabIndex(0)}>Tab 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => setTabIndex(1)}>Tab 2</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        {tabIndex === 0 && (
          <div>
            <h2>Tab 1</h2>
            <p>Content tab 1</p>
          </div>
        )}
        {tabIndex === 1 && (
          <div>
            <h2>Tab 2</h2>
            <p>Content tab 2</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It creates tabs displaying when button is clicked, and everything is fine.

I want to get rid of the two lines with <button...> (in real situation I have many of them).
I tried the following pattern I have ever used in other context and which worked, but here it fails (the tabs don't display except at the first render).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const tabs = [
  { id: "1", value: "Tab 1" },
  { id: "2", value: "Tab 2" }
];

export function App() {
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(1);
  const selectTab = (index) => {
    setTabIndex(index);
  };
  const Tab = ({ keyTab, tab }) => {
    return (
      <button key={keyTab} onClick={() => selectTab(tab.id)}>
        Tab {tab.id}
      </button>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {tabs.map((tab, i) => (
          <Tab key={tab.value + i} tab={tab} />
        ))}
      </div>
      {console.log("tabIndex=" + tabIndex)}
      <div>
        {tabIndex === 1 && (
          <div>
            <h2>Tab 1</h2>
            <p>Other content tab 1</p>
          </div>
        )}
        {tabIndex === 2 && (
          <div>
            <h2>Tab 2</h2>
            <p>Other content tab 2</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I put the data in the tabs array, I took out all of the buttons code in an external Component, and I checked the tabIndex is effectively taken into account, but it doesn't work.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) in your conditional rendering. Your tab `id` values are strings, `'1'` and `'2'` but you compare with `1` and `2`. With strict equality:

```js
'1' === 1 // false
```

The first tab shows on initial render because the state is set as `1`, not `'1'` as it would later on.

To solve this, consider using the same type for everything, such as `number`s:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const tabs = [
  { id: 1, value: "Tab 1" },
  { id: 2, value: "Tab 2" }
];

function App() {
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(1);
  const selectTab = (index) => {
    setTabIndex(index);
  };
  const Tab = ({ keyTab, tab }) => {
    return (
      <button key={keyTab} onClick={() => selectTab(tab.id)}>
        Tab {tab.id}
      </button>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {tabs.map((tab, i) => (
          <Tab key={tab.value + i} tab={tab} />
        ))}
      </div>
      {console.log("tabIndex=" + tabIndex)}
      <div>
        {tabIndex === 1 && (
          <div>
            <h2>Tab 1</h2>
            <p>Other content tab 1</p>
          </div>
        )}
        {tabIndex === 2 && (
          <div>
            <h2>Tab 2</h2>
            <p>Other content tab 2</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Or `string`s:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const tabs = [
  { id: '1', value: "Tab 1" },
  { id: '2', value: "Tab 2" }
];

function App() {
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState('1');
  const selectTab = (index) => {
    setTabIndex(index);
  };
  const Tab = ({ keyTab, tab }) => {
    return (
      <button key={keyTab} onClick={() => selectTab(tab.id)}>
        Tab {tab.id}
      </button>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {tabs.map((tab, i) => (
          <Tab key={tab.value + i} tab={tab} />
        ))}
      </div>
      {console.log("tabIndex=" + tabIndex)}
      <div>
        {tabIndex === '1' && (
          <div>
            <h2>Tab 1</h2>
            <p>Other content tab 1</p>
          </div>
        )}
        {tabIndex === '2' && (
          <div>
            <h2>Tab 2</h2>
            <p>Other content tab 2</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: A beginner mistake! Thank you for your help...